# How to just call Stored Procedure and exit in Oracle

Tags: c#, .net, database, vb.net, oracle

I developing an RPA process using UiPath. I'm facing an issue where in process I need to execute 2 SP in Oracle which each can take hour's to complete. I tried with uipath inbuilt activity to execute SP then kill that activity but that kills the SP execution to, I wanted to know whether is there way in VBnet to just call the SP and not wait for it to complete?

Please for help

Comment: You can create oracle job and run it in stored procedure, it will be execuring in background session

Comment: you can also try using oracle command to execute stored procedure:https://www.toolbox.com/tech/oracle/question/executing-stored-procedures-in-oracle-using-vbnet-121712/

Answer (score 0):

If we conside only Oracle, you can run procedure in background by using DBMS_JOB or newer DBMS_SCHEDULER.

Just submit a job for a single run like this:

```
DECLARE
    job_no NUMBER;
BEGIN
    DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT(job_no, ‘your_proc;’, SYSDATE);
    COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks, one more help buddy can we pass argument with this? sorry for being a noob

Comment: @KISHORE_SHETTY Can you print your procedure signature please. You may include parameters right in 'your_proc;' string or it's possible by using DBMS_SCHEDULER package.